# How to Change Outputs on tflite model via tflite model maker

Tags: tensorflow, tflite

I have created a model which detects objects via android environment. Checking it, the outputs are "locator" and "image". It was an image classification model. I tried 2nd model but it has different output which are "image" "image1" "image2". I thought that was related to model property and tried another training but there was no result which I desired again.  so it didn't work on my side. Trying to make training with the mmodel maker does not provide changing parameters like preferred outputs etc..

Does anyone know how to make a model for tflite which provides desired outputs?